# How do I cite a page in my own book?

Tags: abbreviations, citation

Every so often I want to ask the reader to look back at a page in the current book they have in their hands (my Ph. D. thesis).  If I write something like

> Critically, breaking a mathematical task down into small, individually-masterable steps can help the topic seem less daunting (Mighton, 2003) -- compare Gowers's "quantum of progress" in research mathematics (p. 50).

... it looks vaguely like I'm trying to direct the reader to page 50 of Mighton's book; I'm not.  Is there something akin to "*ibid.*" that I could use instead of the cumbersome

> Critically, breaking a mathematical task down into small, individually-masterable steps can help the topic seem less daunting (Mighton, 2003) -- compare Gowers's "quantum of progress" in research mathematics (p. 50 **of the current work**).

(or similar)?

**Update**

> Critically, breaking a mathematical task down into small, individually-masterable steps can help the topic seem less daunting (Mighton, 2003) -- compare Gowers's "quantum of progress" in research mathematics (**Chapter 3, p. 50**).

A variation on the suggestion from @terdon.  Does this avoid the ambiguity I was alluding to, without being cumbersome?  I'm not sure, but I'll mark the answer as accepted.  I'd still love to know if I can use *c.w.* or similar as an abbreviation for "current work".

Comment: I'd say: (see page 50). Or, better yet: (see Section 3.5). A section number would probably be better because it's less likely to change from version to version; you could add one paragraph to Chapter 1 at the last minute, and repaginate your entire thesis.

Comment: @J.R.-- luckily LaTeX takes care of keeping the cross references consistent!s

Comment: Sorry, I just came upon this question again. The version you chose does not remove ambiguity. You need the _see_ that is the special term used in this context. In the example phrase you have posted, in the absence of _see_, I would think you are referring to chapter 3 of Gower's book, not yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general format would be something like

> see Section X, page Y

As long as you don't include that in the same parenthesis as the citation itself, it is clear that you are referring to the book the reader is holding. The operative word here is *see* a simple page number in parentheses is much more ambiguous.

On a side note, if you're a Mathematician writing a thesis I will assume you are using LaTeX, which provides the `\ref{}` command precisely to facilitate referring to other parts of the same document.

Comment: Would "see Section X, page Y, above" be better?

Comment: Well, not really. If this is several pages away it is not, strictly speaking, above. It is also not necessary, _see Section X, page Y_ is quite clear.

Comment: I'll go with this for now, but I'm open to fancy abbreviations that refine it!